# Passing URL through Spring XML in java class

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber

I want to pass the URL in the XML file of spring and access that Url in the  java class.

This file links with a java file and I want to access this file in the java class file.

```
Hello.XML file
 <beans profile="motzie_qa">
                <bean id="testProperties" class="com.motzie.TestProperties">
                    <property name="baseUrl" value="${10.10.5.88}" />
                    <property name="users">
                        <map>
                            <entry>
                                <key>
                                    <util:constant static-field="com.motzie.bean.User.Role.ADMIN" />
                                </key>
                                <bean class="com.motzie.bean.User">
                                    <constructor-arg value="testadmin@qasource.com" />
                                    <constructor-arg value="admin" />
                                </bean>
                            </entry>
                            <entry>
                                <key>
                                    <util:constant static-field="com.motzie.bean.User.Role.MASTER" />
                                </key>
                                <bean class="com.motzie.bean.User">
                                    <constructor-arg value="test@qasource.com" />
                                    <constructor-arg value="test$123" />
                                </bean>
                            </entry>
                    </map>
                </property>
                </bean>
            </beans>
        </beans>
```

Comment: you can use Java XML - Parsers to get url from XML

Comment: @ankur  I have to use the class file of java
The issue is regarding the autowired of the code. Can you help me out from this?